# Connecting heroku DB with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, heroku

Trying to post webapp on heroku. I made postgres database on Heroku, and I set confiv vars to what I think they should be:

1. DATABASE_PASSWORD to be password that shows in that database
2. DATABASE_URL
3. DATABASE_USERNAME

and in application.properties in my spring boot project i put this

```
spring.datasource.url = ${DATABASE_URL}
```

and same for other properties

and in hibernate.cfg.hml I put this

```
<property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
         ${DATABASE_URL}
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
         ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
         ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      </property>
```

as result I always get

> The application must supply JDBC connections

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot (`application.properties` is a Boot thing), you shouldn't have a `hibernate.cfg` at all. And [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) say that they also add the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_*` variables automatically.

Comment: in hibernate.cfg i have configured my mapping files, and it seems to get all data (including url, username and pass) from hibernate.cfg file... can you please explain one more time where is SPRING_DATASOURCE_*  supposed to be?